# Name for & Examples of CSS Properties can shrink to one or two values

Tags: css

I've searched the W3C CSS2 Spec for the name of the feature that allows us to shrink duplicate values down to one or two like:

```
margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;  -> margin: 1px;
padding: 1px 1px 2px 2px; -> padding: 1px 2px;
```

But I'm still not sure what the exact name for this is. Does anyone know what this is called? Also, can you list some other properties that follow this behavior (besides the obvious ones like `margin`, `padding`, and `border-radius`). I'm writing a regex that matches these properties and would like to include as many them as possible!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd find it useful to look at the source of existing CSS minifiers, for examples: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java

Comment: How did you know I was writing a minifier? :P Thanks for the link. I have indeed been checking out the regexes used in minifiers such as minify (PHP5) but I'll add YUI to my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin` is a shorthand property for `margin-left`, `margin-top`, etc. 
`margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;` and `margin: 1px;` are both shortcuts. In the later one for values collapsed into one. So *collapsing* probably.

As of other shorthands:

- `size` property (from printing module)
- `border-width`, `border-color` and `border-style`
- `background-position`, `background-size`, etc.

Comment: I never considered that the regex would have to match other values besides measurements (like colors or border styles), but that shouldn't be too difficult to implement. Thanks for bringing that to my attention & thanks for your quick response!

Comment: I'm beginning to question whether I need to explicitly match the shorthand names. If I were to take the names out of the expression, would there be any properties with four identical values that don't collapse like `margin`, `border-width`, etc?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: `background-position` is not collapsible.  See:http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-position.

Comment: Good point. I was hoping I wouldn't have to worry with that one because my regex would only match properties with four values, but it's worth a check. Knowing my regex skills, `background-position` may accidentally match!

Answer (score 1):

These are called CSS shorthand properties.

A list of some useful ones can be found here: http://cssdog.com/css_shortcuts.html

If compiling a list of as many as possible is your goal, here is a guide: http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Comment: The second site came up in a Google search for me a few minutes ago. Thanks for the list!

Comment: Note that not all shorthand properties collapse identical values. For example, the "background" shorthand property can combine background-color, background-image, background-repeat, and background-position properties.

Comment: Exactly. But the ones that do contain the same value types (margin's values are all measurements, border-color values are all colors) so the property (or shorthand) name might not matter as long as like values can always collapse.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. Basically what you're saying is: if you always collapse like values, you will never go wrong - that's not to say that you will catch all shorthands like this, but you will never collapse anything that is not meant to be collapsed. Right?

Comment: Exactly! The regex I'm using has a lot of backreferences and I'd rather not have to add the lookahead with all those capture groups (one for each property name) and update each of the backreferences to reflect the capture groups added. I think that we are right in assuming that the regex will never accidentally collapse something that can't be. The shorthands, on the other hand, will be very hard to accomplish with regex. I'll probably just parse them with PHP and combine if necessary.